# PowerShell DSC - how to delete child directories in a path

Tags: powershell, dsc

I've started baby steps in PowerShell DSC.

So far I've created couple of DSC scripts and all working as expected.

I've tried to delete the sub-directories in particular path. But file resource is removing all the sub-folders and parent folder.

I want root folder alive and sub-directories to delete.

Kindly provide suggestions for this task.

Here is my code

```
    #requires -version 4.0
#requires -RunasAdministrator

param(

   [parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
   [string[]]$Computers
)

Configuration RemoveWorkspace{

param(

[parameter(Position=0,Mandatory)]
[string[]]$Computers
)
Node $computers {
File RemoveDiretory{
   Type = "Directory"
   DestinationPath = "E:\Builds\1946"
   Force = $true
   Ensure = "Absent"
   Recurse = $true   

}# end File
}# end node
}#end configuration

#create config data to allow plain text passwords

$configData=@{AllNodes=$null}
#initialize an array for node information
$nodes=@()

ForEach($computer in $Computers){

  write-host " Adding $computer "-ForegroundColor Green
  #define a hashtable for each computername and add to the nodes array

  $nodes+=@{

       NodeName="$computer"
       PSDscAllowPlainTextPassword=$true

  }

}#end foreach

#add the nodes to AllNodes
$configData.AllNodes=$nodes

#you will be prompted to enter a credential

Write-Host "Enter Admin credentials" -ForegroundColor Green

RemoveWorkspace $Computers -configurationdata $configData -outputpath C:\Temp\DeleteDirs\$computer

Start-DscConfiguration -Path C:\Temp\DeleteDirs\$computer -Wait -Verbose -Force
```

I've resolved my issue after little investigation.. i'll publish latest code in some time later

Comment: Are you saying you do not want to / can't use a DSC Script resource to perform the action posted?

Comment: i can't perform the action using DSC File resource.

Comment: Not based on what the docs show relative to the capabilities of the DSC File resource. Yet, that is why the DSC custom resource and script resource exits. To do the things that are not OOBE. Yet, technically, I get what you mean. If I see a file provider from a vendor we auto assume that it is folders are well and that is not always the case. Point of note, if you start trying to use wildcard / multi-file type filters, you are stuck with the same recommendation, at least for now.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say what you issue is, if you do not post your code block for review and comment... but is I take what you say at face value, Quick and dirty, it should be as simple as this.

```
Clear-Host 

remove all subfolders of a given folder 

$RootFolder = 'D:\TestRoot' 
"Showing $RootFolder directories"
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory


Remove these sub dirs only

(Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory) | 
ForEach { Write-Warning -Message "Removing $($_.Name) from $RootFolder" 
Remove-Item $_.FullName #-WhatIf
} 

"Showing $RootFolder directories after remove"
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootFolder -Directory


Results

Showing D:\TestRoot directories


    Directory: D:\TestRoot


Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----      Sun 07 Jan 02018                     TestRootSubDir01
                            02:15                                                                                                            
d-----      Sun 07 Jan 02018                     TestRootSubDir02
                            02:15                                                                                                            
d-----      Sun 07 Jan 02018                     TestRootSubDir03
                            02:15                                                                                                            
WARNING: Removing TestRootSubDir01 from D:\TestRoot
WARNING: Removing TestRootSubDir02 from D:\TestRoot
WARNING: Removing TestRootSubDir03 from D:\TestRoot
Showing D:\TestRoot directories after remove
```

***Update***

As per my comment, with regards to your update/comment, take the above and leverage the below.

DSC Script Resource docs
The Script resource in Windows PowerShell Desired State Configuration (DSC) provides a mechanism to run Windows PowerShell script blocks on target nodes. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/scriptresource

Comment: Thank you for your post. but i need suggestions through DSC and above script will work perfectly when we are running from powershell.

Comment: I've posted code .. look now and review .. if possible please provide your thoughts.

Comment: Based on your update, I'd still suggest you use a script resource or custom resource to accomplish your task.

Comment: Thank you so much @Postanote, I'll try as you suggested.

Comment: No worries, but sure to mark this as answered if it satisfied your request.