# Delete directory content using Azure Automation DSC

Tags: azure, configuration, azure-virtual-machine, azure-automation, dsc

I am using Azure Automation DSC to deploy some basic configurations on my Azure VMs. However, I am struggling to delete recursively all the content of C:/Temp directory and leave the directory as an empty folder.

I am using the following code:

```
$temp_dir           = "C:\temp\"  

File "Clean Temp Folder" # Delete $temp_dir Directory 
        { 
            Ensure          = "Absent" 
            Type            = "Directory" 
            Recurse         = $true 
            DestinationPath = $temp_dir
            Force           = $true 
        }
```

As soon as I assign node configuration to the VM, C:/Temp/ folder gets deleted completely, but if I recreate it manually afterwards it won't be deleted on the next DSC run even though the Force parameter is set to true. 
Any suggestions are very welcome!

Comment: You can refer to [PowerShell DSC - how to delete child directories in a path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48135862/powershell-dsc-how-to-delete-child-directories-in-a-path), [Dsc Configuration - Delete](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/automation/dsc-configuration/delete) and [How to remove a configuration and node from Automation State Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/automation/state-configuration/remove-node-and-configuration-package)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was on the Azure side. While I was registering nodes in DSC, the configuration mode was set to ApplyAndMonitor.
The bad thing is that the setting was not visible for the already registered node, but after re-registering the issue was solved.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X3Z96.png)

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to go with [Script resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/reference/resources/windows/scriptresource?view=dsc-1.1) or else if you want to go with  [File resource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/dsc/reference/resources/windows/fileresource?view=dsc-1.1) only then try something as shown below.

```
$temp_dir           = "C:\temp\"  

File "Clean Temp Folder" # Delete $temp_dir Directory 
        { 
            Ensure          = "Absent" 
            Type            = "Directory" 
            Recurse         = $true 
            DestinationPath = $temp_dir
            Force           = $true 
        }

$temp_dir           = "C:\temp\"  

File "Create empty Temp Folder" # Create empty $temp_dir Directory 
        { 
            Ensure          = "Present" 
            Type            = "Directory" 
            DestinationPath = $temp_dir
            Force           = $true 
        }
```